# MVC JsonSerializer ignores maxJsonLength

Tags: json, ajax

i post ajax with json.stringify(data) by 3413601 length. and on server side it throws error. I cant understand why, because i have options on my web.config:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
  <system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
  </webServices>
</scripting>
```

Its all ignores by compiler, why????

Error text:

> ArgumentException: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property. Parameter name: input

Comment: what kind of error does it throws ?

Comment: perhaps it is violating MaxJsonDeserializerMembers, not maxJsonLength